# How to pass optional view to another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I have this `TestView` which accepts `headerContent` and `bodyContent`,

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
  let headerContent: (() -> Content)?  = nil
  let bodyContent: () -> Content
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      headerContent?()
      bodyContent()
    }

  }
}
```

And I use it as,

```
struct ContentView: View {  
  var body: some View {
    TestView {
      Text("Body Content")
    }
  }
}
```

Now, how do I pass `headerContent`? I tried doing,

```
struct ContentView: View {  
  var body: some View {
    TestView(headerContent: {
      Text("HeaderContent")
    }) {
      Text("BodyContent")
    }
  }
}
```

I get error,

```
Extra arguments at positions #1, #2 in call
Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Way1:

Here is a way, but you would get issue and error if your headerView type be deferent than the body Content! E.g. Circle and Text. I solved this issue in my second Way:

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder let headerContent: (() -> Content)?
    @ViewBuilder let bodyContent: () -> Content
    
    init(headerContent: (() -> Content)? = nil, bodyContent: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.headerContent = headerContent
        self.bodyContent = bodyContent
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return VStack {
            
            headerContent?()
            bodyContent()
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

### Way2:

Here is the right way for you:

```
struct TestView<BodyContent: View, HeaderContent: View>: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder let headerContent: () -> HeaderContent
    @ViewBuilder let bodyContent: () -> BodyContent
    
    init(headerContent: @escaping () -> HeaderContent, bodyContent: @escaping () -> BodyContent) {
        self.headerContent = headerContent
        self.bodyContent = bodyContent
    }
    
    init(bodyContent: @escaping () -> BodyContent) where HeaderContent == EmptyView {
        self.headerContent = { EmptyView() }
        self.bodyContent = bodyContent
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
      return VStack {
            
            headerContent()
            
            bodyContent()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
          
        TestView(headerContent: {
            Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 25, height: 25)
        }, bodyContent: {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        })
            

        TestView(bodyContent: {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        })

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it `var` (ie. changeable) instead of `let`, like

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
  var headerContent: (() -> Content)?  = nil     // << here !!

...
```

Comment: @swiftPunk, it is out of question context.

Answer (score 0):

Change your optional variable from `let` to `var`.

When you define a variable using `let` keyword then you can't change it. In your example, you have set nil as constant for a `headerContent`.

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
    var headerContent: (() -> Content)?  = nil
    let bodyContent: () -> Content
```

You can also use `let` with `init`

```
struct TestView<Content: View>: View {
    let headerContent: (() -> Content)?
    let bodyContent: () -> Content
    
    init(headerContent: (() -> Content)?  = nil, bodyContent: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.headerContent = headerContent
        self.bodyContent = bodyContent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a single view an optional parameter can be done through two different approaches

Way 1 :- with this way you can easily pass view in closure.

```
    struct View<Content: View>: View {
      var content: Content?

      init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content = { EmptyView() }) {
          let view  = content()
          self.content = (view is EmptyView) ? nil : view
      }
      var body: some View {
        if let content = content {
           
        } else {
            
        }
      }
    }
```

Way 2 :- with this way you need to pass view with wrap in `AnyView`

```
    struct View: View {
      var content: AnyView?

      init(content: AnyView? = nil) {
          self.content = content
      }
      var body: some View {
        if let content = content {
           
        } else {
            
        }
      }
    }
```